# Can i use react bootstrap table inside a card?

Tags: reactjs

Hi is anyone know if i can implement table inside a card?
im having error if i add the card.table part. thank you

```
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Table>
    <th></th>
    </Card.Table>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Card.Table>` is not a component. Try using `<Table>` component instead. You can check it out here: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/table/.

I have it in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-thompson-kh12q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React from "react";
import { Card, Table } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td colSpan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please add more details, maybe add a codeSandox to duplicate the issue. Also in the future please use tags and what you have tried, the issues in more detail and in depth so we can help you. :)

Comment: Seems fine. What seems to be the issue now?